# select the row that's "before" a given row in some ordering

Tags: sql, postgresql

What's the idiomatic way to select a row that's identified as the one that's coming up *before* a row we are given?

An example to make this clear:

```
CREATE TABLE entry (x VARCHAR, i INTEGER);
ALTER TABLE entry ADD PRIMARY KEY (x, i);
INSERT INTO entry (x,i) VALUES ('a', 1);
INSERT INTO entry (x,i) VALUES ('a', 2);
INSERT INTO entry (x,i) VALUES ('b', 1);
```

Table 'entry' has a clear lexicographical ordering according to the natural ordering:

```
SELECT * FROM entry ORDER BY x, i
```

If I am given the `b` and `1` (i.e. the `('b', 1)` row) how do I write a query that selects the row that's coming up before that? (i.e. the `('a', 2)` row). The query should return an empty row set if given the "first" row (in the case above, the `('a', 1)` row).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `order by` and `limit` and a `where` clause:

```
select e.*
from entry e
where x < 'b' or x = 'b' and i < 1
order by x desc, b desc
limit 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a LAG Window function.  (also LEAD when appropriate)

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-window.html